# Data format to use on a micro controller and MQTT

Tags: arduino, mqtt, data-formats

I'm using **MQTT** on an **Arduino** to send sensors data to a Javascript page.

Until now I've sent only simple data format: int or floats.

What format can I use to send more complex, structured data?
for example:

```
{ "temperature": 32, "humidity": 67 }
```

I'd like to send it on a single MQTT message.

I could use Json, but I fear it's a bit heavy for an Arduino.

---

**Update**

Ok, seems to be a general consensus on JSON, however I'm a bit concerned about the memory requirement.

I've found two libraries for json encoding/decoding on an Arduino:

- https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson
- https://github.com/interactive-matter/aJson

**ArduinoJson** claims to be less memory consuming, however doesn't support:

- reading from Stream ([latest versions](http://ecafe.org/blog/2014/01/29/stream-support-for-arduino-mqtt-library.html) of the Arduino MQTT library supports receiving 
  messages in streams)
- filtering of incoming json (to selectively parse only required Json fields)

Comment: Hi, I've been around this one as well. I ended up using a Raspberry Pi, with a Gerduino add-on board. I use a private, binary protocol between the Pi and the Arduino (on the Gertboard) and then the Pi maps this to / from JSON, and to/from MQTT topics. Many advantages, with the Pi providing mainstream MQTT , JSON functions and the Arduino doing what it does best.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for an alternative of your private binary protocol, something like protocol buffers or bson, but that can run on a microcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Use the **topics** themselves to structure the data:

```
/home/sensors/count 2
/home/sensors/sensor1/name Kitchen
/home/sensors/sensor1/temperature 21
/home/sensors/sensor1/humidity 47
/home/sensors/sensor2/name Upstairs
/home/sensors/sensor2/temperature 23
/home/sensors/sensor2/humidity 48
```

Publishing many simple messages is easier for a resource constrained Arduino.  The alternative is constructing some large JSON string like you are thinking:

```
/home/sensors = {{"name":"Kitchen", "temperature": 21, "humidity": 47 },
                 {"name":"Upstairs", "temperature": 23, "humidity": 48 }}
```

Also, I think the topics is the more useful design (API) for the both publisher and client.  For the Arduino side, consider how the topic approach does not force every location to have both temperature and humidity sensors?  For the client side, the topic approach allows a use case that shows just the humidity.

Comment: However, I'd like to keep the messages on a single MQTT notify so that the client will receive them in a single event, either for simplicity and for data consistency. For example, I'd like to send the temperature in Celsius OR Faranheit, what will happen if the user change the temperature scale to Celsius? The client will receive first the new scale, and then the new temperature value in the new scale. I'd prefer something like: "temperature":"54|celsius".

Comment: The localization is an interesting question.  I would offer that in a pub/sub system, the subscribers have zero control over what is published.   Put differently, the publisher does not know if there are any subscribers and posts the same topics whether there are 0, 1 or N subscribers.  So for the C/F, I would still say put the locale in the topic:  /home/sensors/sensor1/temperature/C & /home/sensors/sensor1/temperature/F  Similar for language you might have /home/EN/... & /home/DE/...  You see your use case as request/reply; why not stay with HTTP?  The response can be a JSON blob.

Comment: Http and JSON can be heavy on a microcontroller. I'm using a simpler form of Json, when I don't escape strings (I'm sending only simple strings or numbers). Ie: my string can't contains the " or strange characters.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is just publish the temp in Celsius (or Faranheit) from the Arduino to the broker for example

`/raw/sensorid temp`

Then on the broker I transform it all into JSON including adding a timestamp and republish to another topic. I find it easier this way as I don't need to change the arduino code if I move the sensor or have replace it. [Here](https://github.com/matbor/arduinoTemps2mqtt) is the code I use if you are interested, it's using Onewire sensors.

For example;

```
Arduino Publishes:
/raw/DE24532156 10


On my broker I Transforms the data to:
/house/temps {"location":"outside","tempC":10,"tempF":50,"average":14,"max":16,"min":8,"timestamp":12234234}
```

I do all my transformation in python using [mqttwarn](https://github.com/jpmens/mqttwarn).